# ByteBuffer created using NewDirectByteBufer() has no array in it

Tags: java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and i have a requirement of using DirectBuffers to transfer bulk image data from Java to C++ and back from C++ to Java.

I have allocated the direct memory in Java code using allocateDirect and filled it as follows:

```
ByteBuffer myBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
myBuffer.orger(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
myBuffer.put(imageByteArrayData);
SetImage(myBuffer)//MyNativeMethod in JNI
```

AtJni i do:

```
static void SetImage(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject myBuffer)

{
char* marker = (char*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(myBuffer);
gImageProcessor->ProcessImage(marker);//My other cpp class which process this image add some effects
}
```

When i have checked the address of this marker in cpp and myBuffer address in Java (through variables window in debug mode) both are pointing to same address.

Now i have to get this image back in some other Java module which is no way connected with my earlier Java module which has allocated the direct buffer.

So i have called getProcessedImage() method in ImageProcessor.cpp, which will return the char* pointer to JNI.

My Question here is:  How can i return this data to Java without doing extra array copy.  I have tried using NewDirectByteBuffer in JNI as follows:

```
static jobject GetUpdatedImage(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
gData = gImageProcessor->getProcessedImage();
jobject = (jobject)env->NewDirectByteBufer(gData, sizeofgdata);
return jobject;
}
```

But at Java level when i convert jobject to ByteBuffer, i am able to see that the address represented by this object is the same direct address but .hasarray(), .array() and calling any method on it is resulting in a UnSupportedOperationException.

I have searched different posts but not got any information.  Can any one help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Direct buffers don't have an associated backing Java array, at least in the common JVMs; you can't use them as such.  If you need the data in a Java array, once you get the ByteBuffer get, you can use the bulk get() operation to copy the bytes into a Java array.  Or, you can work with the ByteBuffer directly, using get/put as appropriate to read/write data.